# npm scripts ignore errors

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I currently have a npm script for running a linter. Obviously there will be some errors being outputted, but the npm script fails rather than just show me errors and move on.

This is terrible especially when I have something else calling the script as it marvellously breaks everything. I can always run `npm run lint --force` to avoid errors but I don't have that `--force` luxury all the time (for example, with a git-hook).

How can I setup my script to output errors without causing a mess?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the answer:

Simply adding: `exit 0` to the end of the command did it!

Comment: This isn't working for me. Do you write exit 0 in the terminal command or in a file such as package.json?

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins I assume you've solved this by now but my solution is the following to the npm script `"webpack": "webpack || exit 0"`.

Comment: I guess on Windows you can just add ` & rem`

Answer (score 18):

There are a few other options which are cross platform too:

`eslint || true`

For this to work on Windows, you'll need to `npm install cash-true` first

`exitzero eslint`

You'll need to `npm install exitzero` first

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because of the compatility to windows.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Super handy for things like 'mkdir', where the folder might already exist.

Comment: I did a test and, in my configuration, PowerShell complains "'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 2):

I guess solving that in `npm scripts` will always be a bit limited. There is a micro module [runjs](https://github.com/pawelgalazka/runjs) which is a kind of small enhancement for scripts. Thing is that you can run cli commands and handle errors in JS. So you could do something like this (`runfile.js`):

```
import { run } from 'runjs'

export function lint () {
  try {
    run('eslint .')
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error how you want, you can silently just do nothing or re-throw it by: throw e.stack
  }
}
```

then in the console:

```
$ run lint
```